# Swift Issue Listing out a Dynamic Dictionary from JSON

Tags: json, swift, combine

I am trying to build an application which receives a JSON Object from an API endpoint, which then I want to list out in the view. I've watched a lot of videos on this topic, but in each video they use very simplistic JSON Objects as examples and therefore the code they write doesn't really seem to transfer over, giving me errors no matter how I try to format it. The code is as follows

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation

public struct ActivityModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    public let id: Int
    public let name: String
    public let activity_desc: String?
}


public struct ActivitiesModel2: Codable {
    public let location: String
    public let popular: [String:ActivityModel]
}

public struct ActivitiesModel: Codable {
    public let activities: ActivitiesModel2
}

public class ActivityFetcher: ObservableObject {
    var activities: ActivitiesModel?

    init(){
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://mywebsite.com/api/loadapi") else { return }

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in

            do {
                if let d = data {
                    let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode(ActivitiesModel.self, from: d)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.activities = decodedLists
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No Data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ActivityGuestView: View {
    let networkingServiceGeneral = NetworkingServiceGeneral()

    @ObservedObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

    @ObservedObject var fetcher = ActivityFetcher()

    var body: some View {
        // This is where my issues start
        List(fetcher.activities?.activities.popular) { result in
            VStack {
                Text(result.name)
                Text(result.activity_desc)
                    .font(.system(size: 11))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code, as I put it, gives me 5 errors. They are the following;

```
    - Initializer 'init(_:rowContent:)' requires that '(key: String, value: ActivityModel)' conform to Identifiable
    - Initializer 'init(_:rowContent:)' requires that '[String : ActivityModel]' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'
    -Value of optional type '[String : ActivityModel]?' must be unwrapped to a value of type '[String : ActivityModel]'
    - Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'
    - Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'
```

Some of these errors have options to fix it, but when I press fix it adds code but doesn't actually fix the error so I figured to just include them anyways. I'm still fairly new to Swift, but I know what some of it is asking, particularly the conforming to Identifiable, but it says that struct ActivitiesModel does not conform to identifiable when I try to add the tag, and the JSON Object doesn't have an ID for that section, so I can't ask the ID to make it identifiable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this has kind of been a wall right now.

EDIT: Here's the JSON

```
"activities": {
        "location": "Dallas",
        "popular": {
            "10": {
                "id": 38,
                "name": "Adventure Landing Dallas",
                "activity_desc": "Aquatic complex chain with additional land attractions including mini-golf, laser tag & go-karts.",
            },
            "12": {
                "id": 40,
                "name": "Jumpstreet",
                "activity_desc": "None provided.",
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if we saw the JSON you are trying to decode.

Comment: Well I figured the coding structure would say show what the JSON looks like, but I'll add it anyways at the bottom.

Comment: Added JSON at bottom